# How to create a Silverlight class library that is downloaded once, like an assembly

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a website solution that contains three different Silverlight 4 projects, and they all make use of the same Silverlight class library.

I have done this by creating a class library project within the solution, and referencing it from the other Silverlight projects.

BUT the class library is included in every one of the XAPs.  The user could end up downloading the same class library multiple times.

How do I canvert the class library into a XAP that can be downloaded once, in the same way that an assembly is?

(And why isn't there a Silverlight Assembly project type in Visual Studio?)

Answer (score 1):

You should use Assembly Caching - it's a way to leave dependent assemblies out of your xap file. Instead you need to deploy them with your xap file by placing them in a seperate zip file in the same folder.

In the properties window of your Silverlight application you can choose to enable Assembly Library Caching. That will automaticly generate a zip file for each cacheably assembly.

Comment: You will need to make sure that an `extmap` file is created for the dll. http://stulic.blogspot.com/2009/07/assembly-caching-in-silverlight-3.html has some information on this.

Answer (score 0):

In the project References folder in Visual Studio, select the referenced dll that you don't want to be loaded again, and in the Properties window set its Copy Local property to false.